# wordpress: Sort users by “birthday”

Tags: jquery, sql, wordpress

I have created user meta that holds user birthday (birthday).

`birthday` is date field.

I looked at `WP_User_Query` but did not found way to compare only months

Now I am trying to figure how to sort (get) all users that have birthday based on specific month.

I have created drop menu that holds all the months.

```
function users_months_dropdown() {
?> 
<select name="month" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<?php
        submit_button( __( 'Filter Date' ), 'secondary', 'filter_date_action', false );
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', 'users_months_dropdown' );
```

and now I'm stuck with the query

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you use `MONTH(date)` in your query? Take a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)